# Is there a way to remove compactType property from react-grid-layout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-grid-layout

Is there a way to remove a compactType property from react-grid-layout? Because it causes for positions of grid items not to be properly saved, as it seems it render positions from database in vertical or horizontal order.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a prop "compactType = {null}".